# Проблема с использованием рекурсии( вложенные списки)

Tags: python

В данных момент изучаю применение рекурсии на простых задачах. Проблемы начались с работой со вложенными списками.

Для примера код для нахождения четных элементов.

```
def even(element):
    # если просто число, а не список
    if isinstance(element, int):
       return []
    # далее если список
    else:
        ev = []
        for i in element:
            if i % 2 == 0:
               ev.append(i)
    return ev
```

Код работает для int и простого списка:

```
print(even(1))      # []
print(even([1, 2])  # [2]
```

Но я не понимаю как использовать рекурсию для нахождения во вложенном списке типа:

```
[1, [1, 3, [2]], [[8], 4]]
```

Заранее спасибо большое за прояснения!

Comment: Код же не работает для `print(even(2))`

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает самой рекурсии, вызова функцией самой себя. Также советую почитать про разницу между `append` и `extend`. Вот код, который возвращает все чётные числа ища по вложенным спискам:

```
def even(element):
    # если дано число
    if isinstance(element, int):
        # если число чётное
        if element % 2 == 0:
            # вернуть его
            return [element]
        else:
            # иначе пустой список
            return []

    # иначе обработать список
    else:
        # для каждого элемента списка
        res = []
        for el in element:
            # вызвать эту функцию и добавить её результат
            res.extend(even(el))
        return res
```

Обратите внимание, что эта функция всегда возвращает список – несмотря на то, что её аргументом может быть и число, и список. Именно это и позволяет использовать результат функции `even` для расширения (`extend`) результирующего списка.

Ещё рекомендую попробовать самостоятельно просчитать этот код на несложном примере (например, `[1, 4, [2, [7,12]], 6]`), чтобы хорошо понять дерево вызова функций и другие нюансы рекурсии.

Comment: Спасибо! Я реально запутался сначала где вообще вызывать функцию для рекурсии. На примерах фибоначи, факториалов или нахождения сум чисел в списках как-то было понятнее.

Comment: @User007 просто нужно больше практики. А благодарность на этом сайте выражают стрелкой вверх и галкой принятого ответа `;)`

Comment: Наверное, `res += even(el)` будет проще смотреться чем `res.extend(even(el))` :)

Comment: @gil9red так-то да, но на мой взгляд лучше дать человеку понять всю логику, которая здесь происходит, чтобы не было вопросов вроде `А почему append не подходит?` Зато после понимания, что такое `extend`, можно будет просто сказать, что операция сложения делает то же самое.

Comment: @AivanF К сожалению нету репутации, чтобы поставить, но вижу мне уже помогли! Еще раз спасибо за помощь с рекурсией, сейчас изучаю деревья и наконец-то начал ее на полную использовать